# Strange behavior of ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.bidimap.TreeBidiMap

Tags: java, apache-poi

I used poi-3.17 to generate an Excel xls file with two sheets, code for creating the workbook and the 1st sheet looks like:

```
        Sheet sheet;
    Workbook wb;
    String excelFileName = "myExcelFile.xls";
    String sheet1Name = "sheet1";
    // read the excel workbook via input stream if it exists already
    // otherwise create a new workbook
    try {
        if ( new File(excelFileName).exists() )
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(excelFileName));
        else
            wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    }

    // try to remove the sheet1 if it existed already
    try {
        wb.removeSheetAt(wb.getSheetIndex(sheet1Name));
        sheet = wb.createSheet(sheet1Name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sheet = wb.createSheet(sheet1Name);
    }

    // do something here to add contents to the sheets

    // Write the output to a file
    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    try {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My intension is: "sheet1" can be deleted when the program is excuted while "sheet2" (code not shown here) shall be not deleted.

I could run my program if no Excel file exists, an Excel file with 2 sheets will be generated correctly. Even if the Excel file was generated already, I could still run my program without any problem (well, in this case "sheet2" will be the 1st sheet in the Excel file, then "sheet1").

Problem is when I opened the Excel file and do some modification in "sheet1", there will be ClassNotFoundExceptions and no content inside the Excel at all:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/bidimap/TreeBidiMap
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.Section.<init>(Section.java:178)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.MutableSection.<init>(MutableSection.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet.init(PropertySet.java:494)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet.<init>(PropertySet.java:196)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.MutablePropertySet.<init>(MutablePropertySet.java:44)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.SpecialPropertySet.<init>(SpecialPropertySet.java:47)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.DocumentSummaryInformation.<init>(DocumentSummaryInformation.java:99)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySetFactory.create(PropertySetFactory.java:116)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.getPropertySet(POIDocument.java:236)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.getPropertySet(POIDocument.java:197)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.readPropertySet(POIDocument.java:175)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.readProperties(POIDocument.java:158)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.updateEncryptionInfo(HSSFWorkbook.java:2295)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getBytes(HSSFWorkbook.java:1506)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1428)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1414)
at excel.WriteToExcel.<init>(WriteToExcel.java:70)
at main.IndexGenerateFE.main(IndexGenerateFE.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.bidimap.TreeBidiMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

So I added lib "commons-collections4-4.1.jar" in the build path, the Excel file can be generated again correctly even if the contents in "sheet1" is modified. What is the reason? I mean regardless whether "sheet1" is modified or not, I have deleted it already when the program is executed, how could it happen?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. Added lib "commons-collections4-4.1.jar" in the build path and the problem gone. It's the solution

Comment: The OP already knew that: "So I added lib "commons-collections4-4.1.jar" in the build path, the Excel file can be generated again". The question is about *why* this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the command 'workbook.write(out);'.
The error occurs both with jdk-8u144 (POI ... 3.16 and 3.17) as well as with jdk-9 (POI ... 3.17). Since I use '.getCellTypeEnum()' POI ... 3.15 leads to errors when compiling - so does not go either.
So I'm forced to use an old version of my software.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's due to the version of the POI library.
I'm writing a Groovy Script on SoapUI and I was having the same incomprehensible exception.
I've just downloaded and used the 3.14 on SoapUI (I was on 3.17) and no more exception.

Answer (score 0):

seems the problem could be solved if to create "xlsx" file using XSSFWorkbook instead of HSSFWorkbook for "xls" file.